# assembly, how to use mprotect?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, system-calls, mprotect

I am trying to make self modifying code in Linux. I thought it would works but didn't.

```
section .data
section .text
global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 125 ;mprotect syscall number
    mov ebx, _start ; *addr
    mov ecx, 0x10000 ;page interval.
    mov edx, 7 ; rwx permission
    int 0x80
    jmp modify
target:
    mov eax, edx        
halt:
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
modify:
    mov ebx, [new]      
    mov [target], ebx   
    jmp target          
new:
    mov ebx, 0
```

I used nasm on ubuntu 18.04.

INT 0x80 return value is -22 0xffffffea

I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your program under `strace`, like `strace ./a.out` to decode system call args and return values.

Probably your base address isn't page-aligned, or the range includes some unmapped pages.  You could round down to a page boundary with `and ebx, -4096`, or you could align `_start` by putting `align 4096` before it.

Or instead of calling mprotect yourself, you could link your program with `ld --omagic` to make the text segment read+write+exec.

Comment: thanks. only can boundary? umm..! so. how to use align 4096? in assembly. can i get some docs?

Comment: @JaeILRyu https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html `ld` man page.  NASM `align`: https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.11.13.  Google found both of these easily.